# List all taxonomies assigned from a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am really desperate for help here, been trying do this since yesterday and still no luck, so here is what I want to achieve

**Collection** = custom post type

- **Material** = custom taxonomy assigned to "collection"

  - Mat1 = term
  - Mat2 = term
- **Body** = custom taxonomy assigned to "collection"

  - Body1 = term
  - Body2 = term
- **Color** = custom taxonomy assigned to "collection"

  - Color1 = term
  - Color2 = term

The structure will be something like this

```
- Material
  - Mat1
  - Mat2
- Body
  - Body1
  - Body2
- Color
  - Color1
  - Color2
```

I got this code but it's not working at all

```
$post_type = 'collection';
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( (object) array( 'post_type' => $post_type, 'hide_empty' => true ) );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ){
    echo $taxonomy->name;

    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        echo '<li>';
        echo $term->name;
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for [`get_object_taxonomies()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_object_taxonomies) you'll notice a few things, namely that for your purposes you'll want to pass the name of a post type as the first argument, and get the objects with the second. It also appears you're conflating the arguments for both `get_object_taxonomies()` and `get_terms()`.

Also with the [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function, if you're using WP 4.5 or higher, you'll want to pass the taxonomy in the `$args` array.

```
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( 'collection', 'objects' );

foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ){
    echo $taxonomy->name;

    $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy->name,
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ));

    foreach( $terms as $term ){
        echo "<li>{$term->name}</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: How to I change the taxonomy to its name and not slug, in your code its showing its slug and how do I add links to the terms? that is the only thing I need and all is working fine, thank you

Comment: I think I got it, just change it to echo $taxonomy->label; and added the get_term_link() inside the foreach

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response - but yes that's all you needed. For reference you can view an example taxonomy object [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy#Examples)

Comment: Awesome!! - How to get images and experts, been trying, but i only get errors. :/